# Convert string with multiple values into array

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```
var group = "one+two+three";
```

Each value in the string is separated by a `+`, and I wanted to add them separately in an array, so It could then become:

```
var group_array = ["one", "two", "three"];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: While you received several answers already, this is really a thing you should have been able to find with a simple web search, as explained in ["how to ask questions on Stackoverflow"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You really couldn't search for [`[javascript] string to array`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+string+to+array)?

Answer (score 2):

Use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) like

```js
var group = "one+two+three";
var groupArray = group.split('+');
console.log(groupArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it:

```
var groupArray = "one+two+three".split("+");
// -> will give you ["one", "two", "three"];
```

### [**Try**](http://jsfiddle.net/mfgpehzp/9/)